# How can i read values of range, which have been sent to google app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

I want to do something with some cells in Google SpreadSheets.
My app script

```
function abb(cell_address) { 
 Logger.log (cell_address);// ok, for example [[qw], [123]] // wrong loop! 
for (let cells of cell_address)     
{Logger.log (cell);}return;}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[["qw"], [123]]` is an Array of Arrays also called 2D Array. Use nested loops.

```js
// Included to make the code work on Stack Snippet
var Logger = console;
abb([
  ["qw"],
  [123]
]);

function abb(cell_address) {
  Logger.log(cell_address); // ok, for example [[qw], [123]] // wrong loop! 
  for (let row of cell_address) {
    for (let cell of row) {
      Logger.log(cell);
    }
  }
  return;
}
```